# How to extract subpath from a file path by python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract subpath from a list of paths using python:

path structure looks like this:

```
 path= '/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/image.png'
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
'f/g/h/image.png'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
path= '/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/image.png'

cutoff= 6
'/'.join(path.split('/')[cutoff:])
```

**Output:**

```
'f/g/h/image.png'
```

Answer (score 6):

The `relative_to` method on Path works like this. You can use `str` to turn the result into a string, if you prefer.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path('/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/image.png')
>>> path.relative_to('/a/b/c/d/e')
PosixPath('f/g/h/image.png')
>>> str(_)
'f/g/h/image.png'
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to